# List of users with NO mobile device in exchange

Tags: powershell, mobile, activesync

I would like to export a list of users that have no mobile device associate in Exchange online.

using Powershell

Get-MobileDevice | export-csv test.csv

I am able to get a list of everyone who HAS a mobile device, but I would like the opposite effect.  We have  a company policy that requires email synced to mobile and this info will hep me perform an audit of employees.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Think simple: generate a list of all users, generate a list of all mobile device users, and compare both of them => done.